# MongoDB: Use $lookup aggregation in countDocuments()

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to make a pagination and would like to use the mongoDB's countDocuments() method to return the total number of teams who's leader belongs to DC organization.

teams collection:

```
{
   _id: 1,
   name: 'avengers',
   leader_id: 'L1'
},
{
   _id: 2,
   name: 'justice league',
   leader_id: 'L2'
},
{
   _id: 3,
   name: 'suicide squad',
   leader_id: 'L3'
}
```

leaders collection:

```
{
   _id: 'L1',
   name: 'ironman',
   organization: 'MCU'
},
{
   _id: 'L2',
   name: 'superman',
   organization: 'DC'
},
{
   _id: 'L3',
   name: 'harley quinn',
   organization: 'DC'
}
```

My question is, can we use the $lookup aggregation as the query to match my output?

Comment: What is the language you use

Comment: I use nodejs @varman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `countDocuments` does not take aggregation operators in its argument.  You can use the [$count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/index.html#count-aggregation) stage to get the count of documents in the pipeline.